# Beamer \only command messes up tabular

Tags: tables, beamer, only

In beamer, I'm trying to create a row-by-row tabular set of slides: each slide exposes a new row. I've solved a lot of problems, but I'm still having issues with a extra partial row being generated.  (See picture) If I comment out the invisible rows, no extra row is generated. But of course I lose the row-by-row display I'm after.

Thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Please help us to help you by providing a so called minimal working example (MWE) something that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and specially not a screenshot.

Comment: You can't use only inside a tabular environment... You could cut the tabular into complete pieces (each one inside an `\only` command and being a complete tabular) instead and add an appropriate space (computed through a `savebox` by `\ht\mybox` and `\dp\mybox` and another `\savebox` of the whole tabular that will give the appropriate vertical space needed in each \only command)... It is somehow complicated but possible. Please follow the commant of @HafidBoukhoulda in order to get a possible answer that fit your needs.

Comment: So why can't \only be used in tabular environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following defines a command `\tableonly` that should work inside a `tabular` environment (it did for my small test file).

Have fun with it.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype\math[1]{>{\(}#1<{\)}}
\newcounter{iteration}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\tableonly%>>>
  {%
    \omit\@ifnextchar<\table@only\table@@only
  }%<<<
\protected\long\def\table@only<#1>#2%>>>
  {%
    \gdef\beamer@doifnotinframe{\cr}%
    \def\beamer@doifinframe{\cr#2}%
    \beamer@masterdecode{#1}%
    \beamer@donow
  }%<<<
\protected\long\def\table@@only#1%>>>
  {%
    \beamer@ifnextcharospec{\table@@@only{#1}}{\cr#1}%
  }%<<<
\long\def\table@@@only#1<#2>%>>>
  {%
    \gdef\beamer@doifnotinframe{\cr}%
    \def\beamer@doifinframe{\cr#1}%
    \beamer@masterdecode{#2}%
    \beamer@donow
  }%<<<
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{table}{example}% >>>
  \only<1->
    {%
      \begin{tabular}[]{|\math{c}||*3{\math{c}|}}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c||}{Iteration} & x & d & s \\
        \hline
        \hline
        \tableonly<2->{0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\\hline}
        \tableonly<3->{1 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\\hline}
        \tableonly<4->{2 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\\hline}
        \tableonly<5->{3 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\\hline}
      \end{tabular}%
    }%
\end{frame}% <<<

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 but it has problems if a word in second line fore example is longer that the word in the word of the same column before it appears...

Comment: @koleygr that's naturally, `\only` does never preserve the space.

Comment: Thanks @Skillmon... I forgot that because I supposed the op would like to show the tabular part by part without "jumbs" through slides

Comment: Thanks for the answer- but this will take me about 4 hours of study to understand :-)

Comment: @theHampster all it does is add `\omit` and `\cr` to the code of `\only`, the rest is copy paste of beamer's code.

Comment: @koleygr I'm afraid there is no real way to achieve this with `\visible` in a similar manner to my `\tableonly`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way in my comment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newsavebox\wholeTabular
\newsavebox\partTabular
\newsavebox\fullPartTabular
\newsavebox\LongerWordBox
\newcommand\readWhole[2]{\savebox\wholeTabular{\vbox{\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{#1}#2\end{tabular}\end{center}}}}
\newcommand\readPart[2]{\savebox\partTabular{\vbox{\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{#1}#2\end{tabular}\end{center}}}\savebox\fullPartTabular{\vbox{\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{#1}#2\end{tabular}\vspace*{\dimexpr\ht\wholeTabular+\dp\wholeTabular-\ht\partTabular-\dp\partTabular}\end{center}}}}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}

\readWhole{lll}{%
First & 1-1 & 1-2\\
Second & 2-1 & 2-2\\
Third & 3-1 & 3-2
}

\savebox\LongerWordBox{Second}

\readPart{lll}{%
\parbox[t]{\wd\LongerWordBox}{First\hfill} & 1-1 & 1-2\\}

\only<1>{\usebox\fullPartTabular}

\readPart{lll}{%
First & 1-1 & 1-2\\
Second & 2-1 & 2-2\\}

\only<2>{\usebox\fullPartTabular}

\only<3>{\usebox\wholeTabular}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]